# Using WebGrid in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid` control in ASP.NET Core application,
I am getting the below error while rendering the grid

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: httpContext

System.Web.HttpContextWrapper..ctor(HttpContext httpContext)
```

at line

```
System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid objWebGrid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(Model.MeetingsObj);
```

Model:

```
public class Meeting
    {

        public int MeetingId { get; set; }
        public string MeetingName { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeetingVM
    {
        public Meeting MeetingObj { get; set; }
        public List<Meeting> MeetingsObj { get; set; }
        public Boolean ShowGridHeader { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone provide solution for the above error?

Comment: What is the value of `Model.MeetingsObj`?

Comment: @Luke , Model.MeetingsObj is a list

Comment: Please can you show us the definition of the list and any objects that it contains

Comment: @Luke, Added the model definition in question,

Comment: @Luke, the above code works fine in MVC5 app, I am getting the error only in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may try to use another component , i recommend the MVC6 grid 
http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/

basically it use almost same syntax ,so there will be minor changes to your current code ,please check the below sample code

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonModel>

@(Html
.Grid(Model)
.Build(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
    columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");

    columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
    columns.Add(model => model.Birthday).Titled("Birth date");
    columns.Add(model => model.IsWorking).Titled("Employed");

//popup part
columns.Add(model => $"<a  data-modal='' data-id=\"{model.Id}\"     href='PasswordRestUser/{model.Id}'      id=\"ss\"  asp-    action=\"PR\" asp-route-id=\"@item.Id\" class=\"btn     btn-info\" '> PR <span class='glyphicon      glyphicon-user'> </span> </a>").Encoded(false);

})
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
)

<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it also has many other features that will make thing easier with .netcore

Comment: It is similar to GRID.MVC in ASP.NET MVC but i has some issue like u need to pull entire model once and on that rows it play filtering, if we take 3 to 5 lakhs of records then it will start performance issue

Comment: you can overcome this part by using the manual paging ,and do the paging part yourself , it is simple i believe ,please check the sample, http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/ManualPaging

Comment: @Ali I like ur solution even in 2019 how would one use edit and delete buttons with the grid is their an easy way for a popup with the mv6 grid

Comment: sorry i missed your comment , unfortunately not with MVC grid , there is another solution for that http://jtable.org/ ,it od exactly what you need ,please check it ,

Comment: Thanks!  I like the jtable and the mvc-6 grid.  Thanks for mentioning these.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Client side Grid (jQuery DataTables Grid With ASP.NET CORE MVC) which is simple, lightweight and open Sources.

[image]

**Script and Css Required for DataTables Grid**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>
```

**Complete code Snippet of ShowGrid View**

```
@{  
    Layout = null;  
}  

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>  

<div class="container">  
    <br />  
    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">  
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">  
            <thead>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>CustomerID</th>  
                    <th>Name</th>  
                    <th>Address</th>  
                    <th>Country</th>  
                    <th>City</th>  
                    <th>Phoneno</th>  
                    <th>Edit</th>  
                    <th>Delete</th>  
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
        </table>  
    </div>  
</div>  

<script>  

        $(document).ready(function ()  
        {  
            $("#example").DataTable({  
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar  
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side  
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)  
                "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once  
                "ajax": {  
                    "url": "/DemoGrid/LoadData",  
                    "type": "POST",  
                    "datatype": "json"  
                },  
                "columnDefs":  
                [{  
                    "targets": [0],  
                    "visible": false,  
                    "searchable": false  
                }],  
                "columns": [  
                    { "data": "CustomerID", "name": "CustomerID", "autoWidth": true },  
                    { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },  
                    { "data": "Address", "name": "Address", "autoWidth": true },  
                    { "data": "Country", "name": "Country", "autoWidth": true },  
                    { "data": "City", "name": "City", "autoWidth": true },  
                    { "data": "Phoneno", "name": "Phoneno", "autoWidth": true },  
                    {  
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta)  
                        { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/DemoGrid/Edit/' + full.CustomerID + '">Edit</a>'; }  
                    },  
                    {  
                        data: null, render: function (data, type, row)  
                        {  
                            return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.CustomerID + "'); >Delete</a>";  
                        }  
                    },  
                ]  

            });  
        });  


    function DeleteData(CustomerID)  
        {  
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ...?"))  
            {  
                Delete(CustomerID);  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                return false;  
            }  
        }  


        function Delete(CustomerID)  
    {  
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "DemoGrid/Delete";  

            $.post(url, { ID: CustomerID }, function (data)  
                {  
                    if (data)  
                    {  
                        oTable = $('#example').DataTable();  
                        oTable.draw();  
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        alert("Something Went Wrong!");  
                    }  
                });  
    }  

</script>
```

**Complete code Snippet of DemoGridController**

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;  
using ExampleGrid.Models;  
using System.Linq.Dynamic;  
// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860  

namespace ExampleGrid.Controllers  
{  
    public class DemoGridController : Controller  
    {  
        private DatabaseContext _context;  

        public DemoGridController(DatabaseContext context)  
        {  
            _context = context;  
        }  
        // GET: /<controller>/  
        public IActionResult ShowGrid()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  

        public IActionResult LoadData()  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();  
                // Skiping number of Rows count  
                var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();  
                // Paging Length 10,20  
                var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();  
                // Sort Column Name  
                var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();  
                // Sort Column Direction ( asc ,desc)  
                var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();  
                // Search Value from (Search box)  
                var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();  

                //Paging Size (10,20,50,100)  
                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;  
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;  
                int recordsTotal = 0;  

                // Getting all Customer data  
                var customerData = (from tempcustomer in _context.CustomerTB  
                                    select tempcustomer);  

                //Sorting  
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection)))  
                {  
                    customerData = customerData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);  
                }  
                //Search  
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))  
                {  
                    customerData = customerData.Where(m => m.Name == searchValue);  
                }  

                //total number of rows count   
                recordsTotal = customerData.Count();  
                //Paging   
                var data = customerData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();  
                //Returning Json Data  
                return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });  

            }  
            catch (Exception)  
            {  
                throw;  
            }  

        }  
    }  
}
```

[Link for Detail Article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-core-mvc/)

Comment: do you have a .net core 2.0 example?

Comment: @OracularMan same can be used with ASP.NET CORE 2.0 no issue in it

Comment: Following it to the "t". made sure @{  
    Layout = null;  
}   getting the following errors 

[Error] TypeError: $('#dialog').dialog is not a function. (In '$('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 360
    })', '$('#dialog').dialog' is undefined)
 Global Code (Definition:69)

and...

TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('#grid').grid...')

Comment: @OracularMan are you using jquery dialog in you application. it is missing script reference.

Comment: using your awesome tutorial at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-core-mvc/ now. Added System.Linq.Dynamic.Core; and Orderby works too. developing using .NET Core 2.0 VS 2017. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I port open sourced WebGrid using ASP.NET Core and package is now on NuGet AndreyKurdiumov.AspNetCore.Helpers - version 0.2.0

This package trying to be in-place replacement for the WebGrid usage.
But I don't yet manage to make this happens 100%.

Changes which should be done

1. Add following lines in the `_ViewImports.cshtml`

   ```
   @using AndreyKurdiumov.AspNetCore.Helpers
   @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
   ```
2. Where WebGrid constructed should be add contructor parameter HttpContextAccessor

   ```
    var grid = new WebGrid(HttpContextAccessor, source: this.Model.Tables,
            defaultSort: "TableName",
            rowsPerPage: 30);
   ```

This is as simple as possible for migration existing codebase which I manage to implement.

The source code
https://github.com/kant2002/AspNetCore.Helpers