# WebGrid in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, webgrid

```
@using System.Web.Helpers

 @{
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
    }

        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "WebGrid",
          headerStyle: "header",
          alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
          selectedRowStyle: "select",
          columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column("UploadBy", "UploadBy"),
          grid.Column("UploadPath", "UploadPath")
         ))
```

The above code gives an error in @grid.GetHtml like

> Reference to type 'IHtmlString' claims it is defined in System.Web, but it is not found

I tried to add a reference dll, but it is not accepted. What should be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WebGrid in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323481/using-webgrid-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: If you trurn on detailed build output, do you get any build warnings about references that can't be resolved? You may need to edit your assembly bindings in Web.Config

Comment: Have you tried adding `using  System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid;` on top code ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use another component , i recommend the MVC6 grid http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/

basically it use almost same syntax ,so there will be minor changes to your current code ,please check the below sample code

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonModel>

@(Html
.Grid(Model)
.Build(columns =>
{
columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");

columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
columns.Add(model => model.Birthday).Titled("Birth date");
columns.Add(model => model.IsWorking).Titled("Employed");
})
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
)
```

it also has many other features that will make thing easier with .netcore